# Is there a CALL instruction that supports register-indirect addressing with an offset?

Tags: assembly, x86

If I have a module's base address at `EAX` and want to call a function located at `EAX+C`, is there a one-line alternative to the following code?

```
ADD EAX, C
CALL EAX
```

It seems like `CALL [EAX+C]` gives undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

`call eax` is [Register indirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Register_indirect), it calls the routine whose address is in *EAX*.
`call [eax+C]` is [Memory indirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Memory_indirect), it calls the routine whose address is in *MEM[EAX + C]*.

That's why they have different behaviors.
The form `call eax+C`, which would be *Register Indirect with Offset*, is not supported by x86.
There is no single instruction that would do.